# how can i prove the fundamental theorem of difference calculus?

Tags: numerical-methods

It states that nth difference of a polynomial of n degree is constant thus (n+1)th difference will be zero.

- how can i show that the nth difference is constant?
- forward difference of a constant is zero but how can i prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x) = c$, where $c$ is a constant. Then $p(x+h)-p(x) = c-c=0$, thus forward difference of a constant is zero.

Let $p(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_k x^k$. Then $p(x+h)-p(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_k ((x+h)^k - x^k)$.

$(x+h)^k-x^k = {0 \choose k} h^0 x^k + {1 \choose k} h^1 x^{k-1} + \dots + {k \choose k} h^k x^0 - x^k = {1 \choose k} h^1 x^{k-1} + \dots + {k \choose k} h^k x^0$. Thus, forward difference of degree $k$ polynomial is a degree $k-1$ polynomial. Use induction to prove that $n$-th forward difference of a $n$ degree polynomial is a $0$ degree polynomial, which is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: i) Use induction and $f^{(n)}(x)=n!$ where $f(x)=x^n$

ii) For $f(x)=c$ you have $f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{c-c}{x-x_0}=0$

Comment: but i have to prove it using forward difference operator

Comment: forward difference of f(x) = f(x+h) - f(x). its different from the differentiation operator D.

Comment: both? or only second one?

Comment: I edit it. is it ok now?

Comment: i have to proof whole theorem using forward difference operator ... these two are the two steps to prove the theorem so both....

Comment: see NUMERICAL METHODS FOR SCIENTISTS AND ENGINEERS
 By K. SANKARA RAO page 104 it take too much time to type

Comment: just saw the proof, its really easy to understand now...